# Where and when should I call TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization()?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions

For different reasons we have implemented our own PlatformTransactionManager which delegates to a "real" TransasctionManager.

One goal of this is to be able to perform indexing (using Solr) whenever a transaction completes successfully. Inside the transaction we have built up a collection of entities that need to be indexed. If the transaction commits the collection is flushed and processed, if it's a rollback the collection is discarded.

I recently came across PlatformTransactionManager and it seems like a good fit to handle this. (fwiw: This project uses Spring's TransactionTemplate instead of @Transactional). Here's how it' currently handled:

```
@Override
public TransactionStatus getTransaction(TransactionDefinition definition) throws TransactionException {
    TransactionStatus transactionStatus = delegate.getTransaction(definition);
    if (!TransactionSynchronizationManager.getSynchronizations().contains(this)) {
        TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(this);
    }
    return transactionStatus;
}

@Override
public void afterCompletion(int status) {
    switch (status) {
    case STATUS_COMMITTED:
        notifyCommit();
        break;
    case STATUS_ROLLED_BACK:
        notifyRollback();
        break;
    }
}
```

I cannot find any good documentation on how to do this kind of synchronization.

- Is there a better way to check if I've already added a synchronization?
- Is it OK to do this inside the getTransaction method of the transaction manager?
- Should I perform any manual cleanup?

Comment: This exactly why I dislike spring, it is never standard, this is a pseudo implementation of JTA without being a real one so your code will get more and more spring dependent, it is endless. You may find a way but when you will upgrade it could probably stop working anymore. You should do it using the TransactionManager instead because it is standard

Comment: The main reason this class is appealing to me is because I believe this will be less prone to errors related to propagation modes and nested transactions. Less prone as in I will not add bugs because of my own transaction status interpretations.

Comment: I think you have to do it very soon after the call to getting a transaction. It is not intuivite that it is static but it will pluck it from threadlocal.